# Flutter primarySwatch changes text colors and icon colors

Tags: flutter, themes

I am currently getting into using Themes in Flutter. I don't fully understand the primarySwatch yet.

I am setting an app wide theme in the `MaterialApp` class. I wan tto change the primarySwatch, so all the buttons I use within the app have the same color. When I use `primarySwatch: Colors.blue`, the text and icons inside the buttons, inside the appBar and so on are white. When I use `primarySwatch: Colors.orange`, the text is black. I found out that there are "bright" and "dark" colors, and probably according to that, the text color changes from white to black. But is there a way to use a "bright" color and still have white texts and icons without overriding all of them?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I didn't see that the question asked "without overriding all of them"

You may want to create a `TextButtonThemeData` in your `ThemeData` like so:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(
              TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So this would mean that I have to override every text color again, right? This is actually what I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm sorry I just reread your question and seen that my answer is not what you asked for.

Comment: @Apri what about using https://pub.dev/packages/theme_provider ? Most of the overrides are already made and you just have to select two colors per theme?

Comment: theme_provider also uses `ThemeData` with primarySwatch. My problem is not switching between themes. My problem is that setting primarySwatch to certain colors also changes the text color of many widgets from white to black, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Apri did you manage to find a solution for this or atleast a work around?